# angular show full text button opens all div containers

Tags: angular

i have some div containers which includes a long text. To shorten it up i decided to use a "show more " button to show only full text if needed. To do so i created this logic in my component class:

```
showShortDesciption = true

 alterDescriptionText() {
this.showShortDesciption = !this.showShortDesciption;
}
```

here is my css class:

```
.show-less {
 text-overflow: ellipsis;
 display: -webkit-box;
 -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
 -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  overflow: hidden;
 }
```

`
and here is one of my div's all of them has the same code and logic:

```
 <mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Peter Hans Testuser</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>

          <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        </mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>

        <div [ngClass]="{'show-less': showShortDesciption}">
          <div [ngClass]="{'show-less': showShortDesciption}">
            <!-- Your Text Here -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="alterDescriptionText()">
          {{ showShortDesciption ? 'SHOW ALL': 'SHOW LESS' }}
        </button>

      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
```

the problem is that if i click at one button to show its full text, it shows every card with its full text.

Comment: What did you expect? You have one flag for multiple divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass id and check id for the particular id exist on containing div
example here
in your ts file

```
showShortDesciption = true
id:number;
 alterDescriptionText(id) {
this.id=id
this.showShortDesciption = !this.showShortDesciption;
}
```

in your html

```
<mat-card class="example-card">
      <mat-card-header>
        <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image"></div>
        <mat-card-title>Peter Hans Testuser</mat-card-title>
        <mat-card-subtitle>

          <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star checked"></span>
          <span class="fa fa-star"></span>
        </mat-card-subtitle>
      </mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-content>

        <div id="1" [ngClass]="{'show-less': showShortDesciption&&id==1}">
          <div [ngClass]="{'show-less': showShortDesciption&&id==1}">
            <!-- Your Text Here -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </mat-card-content>
      <mat-card-actions>
        <button mat-button (click)="alterDescriptionText()">
          {{ (showShortDesciption&&!id==1) ? 'SHOW ALL': 'SHOW LESS' }}
        </button>

      </mat-card-actions>
    </mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily solve this problem using a custom variable in your array (if you are iterating one with an `ngFor`). Let's take as example this simple interface:

```
export interface myData {
  text: string;
  showMore?: boolean;
}
```

let's also imagine that the array is populated only with the `text` property :

```
data: myData[] = [
  {
    text: 'some text'
  },
  {
    text: 'some text'
  },
  {
    text: 'some text'
  },
  {
    text: 'some text'
  },
];
```

`Before` iterating this array, you could manually set the `showMore` propery to be false :

```
this.data.forEach(element => {
  element.showMore = false;
});
```

In the html:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of data">
  <div [ngClass]="[item.showMore ? 'css-class-for-all-text' : 'css-class-for-reduced-text']">
    {{item.text}}
  </div>
  <div class="your-button" (click)="toggleShowMore(item)">
    {{item.showMore ? 'Show less' : 'Show more'}}
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Finally, the `toggleShowMore` function :

```
toggleShowMore(item: myData ): void {
  item.showMore = !item.showMore;
}
```

> If you are NOT iterating an array

There are different ways to achieve this behavior, I'll edit this answer in case.

Answer (score 0):

Using little code, you can add a template reference variable to each div then reference each from the button by template name to add / remove (toggle) the class with a bit of js:

```
<div #myDiv></div>

<button (click)="myDiv.classList.contains('show-less') ?  
    myDiv.classList.remove('show-less')  
     : myDiv.classList.add('show-less')">Change</button>
```

It will also work inside a loop. e.g:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myItems">
    <div #myDiv>Test</div>
    <button (click)="myDiv.classList.contains('someClass') ?  
    myDiv.classList.remove('someClass')  
     : myDiv.classList.add('someClass')">Change</button> 
 </div>
```